# CSS Transparent text on image with coloured box outline

Tags: css, image, text, transparent

After doing some research and finding nothing I was wondering if anyone knows a way to have some text that is transparent over an image but has a box around it so it is still legible.

### My attempt

#### HTML

```
<img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/8000000/Mountains-mountains-and-waterfalls-8031277-2560-1817.jpg"/>

<p> this is some transparent text with a brown background </p>
```

#### CSS

```
img{
  width:500px;
}
p{
  top:100px;
  left:20px;
  position:absolute;
  display:box;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  background:brown;

}
```

### Desired Effect

[image: Desired effect]

Comment: @russell I'm only asking out of curiosity as to whether it can be done with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the fiddle

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDwUb/)

Here's the css

```
.gradient4 {
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
background: url(http://www.silenceit.ca/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/wood_texture.jpg) repeat;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.test{
    background-color:red;
}
.outer{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background: url(http://www.silenceit.ca/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/wood_texture.jpg)
}
```

But here's a crck you need to set the background of the red colored divs text exactly at the same x and Y where you want the text. :)

Comment: Anobik Dey, i didn't get ur crack!!

Comment: @anobik does this basically set the colour of the text to the image of the background

Comment: actually the crack is it sets the background of the text same as the background(big) image. Now with a little positioning of the text background image it will fit exactly on the big Image.. and the other part is in images where small text are rendered you can see the clouds in the text might not match the actual clouds but since rendring area is smll it is negligible also . :)

Answer (score 4):

In that picture of your desired effect, it's not going to work like that.  There, the image is the bottom layer, the brown box is the middle layer, and the text is on top.  If the text were transparent, then the brown box would show through, not the image.

It seems like what you really want is to have a text-shaped hole cut into a box, which I don't think is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
background: url(images/wood_texture.jpg) repeat;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
```

but this stuff is still a working standard! See the resource for implementation and let me know if you need anything else! :)

**RESOURCE**
http://www.silenceit.ca/2011/03/11/css-gradients-and-webkit-image-masks-on-text/

Comment: @andi: It would; you would have the main image, with the brown box inside that, and inside that a text element with the same image as its background, shifted to align and then masked as in the post cited.

Comment: But that would require the text box to be in a known position.  Maybe that's ok with the OP, not sure.

Comment: @andi as I dont have a project in mind where this is needed. I was just curious as to whether it can be done.  as you point out I guess there is no way with only css if you dont know where the text will be positioned on the image